# Is there a faster way to query a database for a specific entry than by its ID?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

If you have a database of 100,000,000,000 records and you know you need entry 51,293,128,345 is there anything faster than

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE entry="51293128345"
```

If you know exactly what you need and what row it is, does the database still need to scan through all preceding records to reach that one.

Comment: "Does the database still need to scan through all preceding records to reach that one?" - Not if you have an index on that column.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE entry=51293128345` might be better suited - it will work on non en_US versions.

Comment: @EugenRieck Whoops, I had intended to remove the ","s but I just copied it from above and forgot.

Comment: To @Blorgbeard, if you don't have an index is there anything else that can be done?

Comment: What Blorgbeard said is very important. In addition to that, your description seems very algorithmic: I mean a high level description. Does your db really have a column named "entry"?

Comment: Well, no. without an index, the table's rows have no defined order, so the only way to find the row with a particular ID is to loop through each row until you find it.

Comment: If you don't have an index and can't or may not create one, you should  really talk to the schema designer.

Comment: If you have a table with 100 billion records, and you want to randomly access it, you should definitely have an index.

Comment: @Blorgbeard at what point do indexes become useful? 1000 record, 10,000 records?

Comment: Depends on a lot of things: the table (columns, sizes), indexed columns, the queries that will hit it.. I guess all I can say is, once a table-scan becomes "too slow" (and you'll have to decide what that means), look at adding an appropriate index.

Comment: Indexes typically introduce a write cost in favor of saving read costs. A table scan without an index will be for example O(n) usually, while an index seek can be anywhere between O(log(n)) to closer to O(1). Without an index, the write cost can be close to O(1) for an insert, and if it needs to find the record for an update, closer to O(n). With an index, writes can be anywhere between O(log(n)) to O(log(n^2)) depending on if rebalancing the index (tree) needs to occur. In other words, if you need fast reads, use an index. If you mainly need fast inserts, maybe no index, unless updates.

Comment: And @therewillbesnacks makes good points too - indexes are not free.

Comment: @therewillbesnacks fantastic, just the information I was looking for.

Comment: Moreover, there are some other costs of writing an index, in terms of power and how many indexes. The typical behavior is significantly faster, more scalable reads, while impacts pro/con on insert/delete/update depending on the implementation of the index, or more precisely in MySQL more like my previous comment. If you want faster access than a key index, why not avoid going to mysql and use a caching layer, for example you could use Redis and load most of the dataset in memory if that is possible. You can tune mysql though to also load more into memory and that will be faster (if avail. mem)

Comment: For just checking to see if a row exists, and I'm worried about performance, I would use "select count('x') from table where id=1234"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: The fastest way to get a single record in an SQL database with a large number of records would be using a where condition on a dense indexed column - `where myindexedcolumn = 1234567`.

---

I gather your column name `entry` is just a generalised term in this case, but if `entry` does not have an index and that is the column you need to query on, then you have some considerations:

1. Add an index on `entry` (as @therewillbesnacks mentioned, indexes improve the select at the expense of an added cost to updates/inserts). However, if `entry` isn't unique and and contains large number of duplicates, then the db query optimiser may still ignore it and scan the whole table.
2. If possible query on an indexed column as well as `entry` - e.g.

   `WHERE myindexedcolumn = 1234 AND entry = "51293128345"`
3. Another consideration is using a completely different database type where entry was a direct path to the required record e.g. Redis or the like (Never used it but I have heard good things). This isn't a suggestion as such, but if you seriously have to query tables with 100 billion records, you may want to investigate additional out of the box optimisation.